# XAMPP Localhost Access Forbidden Error 403 after updating to MacOS Catalina

Tags: xampp, localhost, macos-catalina

XAMPP (7.1) stopped working after updating to MacOS Catalina(10.15). localhost (including virtual host) Access is Forbidden with Error 403. However, http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ is working fine.

It was all working fine with Mojave(10.14.6).

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have fixed the issue by moving my project folders from "/Users/**MY_USER**/Documents/Projects" to "/Users/**MY_USER**/Projects".

However, if someone finds out the solution without moving the folder - please DO share!